# SQL Server 2005 : If statement with return value

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am trying to achieve simple task: select the value from 2 columns in a table.

If one of the values is null then return null, or something.

Else return the values.

```
SELECT 
    MobileAreaCode, Mobile 
FROM 
    TABLE_NAME
WHERE 
    id = 123456789

IF (MobileAreaCode is NULL OR Mobile is NULL)
BEGIN
   RETURN(1)--NULL
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   RETURN(MobileAreaCode+Mobile)
END
```

Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your comment to me, this is what you are looking for:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE PRO_NAME (Identification INT)
AS SELECT
CASE WHEN CONVERT(MobileAreaCode, int)>1 OR
CONVERT(Mobile, int)>1 THEN MobileAreaCode+Mobile
End FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE Hp=(Identification)
GO
```

Older ideas/information..
Give this a try..

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT 
CASE WHEN MobileAreaCode is NOT NULL OR Mobile is NOT NULL THEN
MobileAreaCode+Mobile
END
FROM 
    TABLE_NAME
WHERE 
    id = 123456789
```

Another way..

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT 
CASE WHEN CONVERT(MobileAreaCode, int)>1 OR CONVERT(Mobile, int)>1 THEN MobileAreaCode+Mobile End 
END
FROM 
TABLE_NAME
WHERE 
id = 123456789
```

Using ISNULL..

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT 
CASE WHEN NOT ISNULL(MobileAreaCode, 000) OR NOT ISNULL(Mobile, 000) THEN MobileAreaCode+Mobile End 
END
FROM 
TABLE_NAME
WHERE 
id = 123456789
```

Comment: sorry for bringing it up now, if i want to add support for empty strings don't i just add MobileAreaCode<>''  OR Mobile<>''

Comment: MobileAreaCode and Mobile are NVARCHAR

Comment: MobileAreaCode and Mobile are NVARCHAR

Comment: You can also leverage the following:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx for the use of ISNULL .  However, need to make you aware of the note between ISNULL versus IS NULL..  Read toward the bottom of the page.

Comment: I previously commented incorrectly..  If mobile and mobileAreacode are numbers.. Hmm.. CASE WHEN CONVERT(MobileAreaCode, int)>1 OR CONVERT(Mobile, int)>1 THEN MobileAreaCode+Mobile End

Comment: from what is see CONVERT function converts the value to int in this case, don't you suppose to use something like length?

Comment: it's just don't want to work:)                                      ALTER PROCEDURE PRO_NAME
 ()Identification INT
AS
 SELECT 
 CASE WHEN CONVERT(MobileAreaCode, int)>1 OR CONVERT(Mobile, int)>1 THEN MobileAreaCode+Mobile End 
 END
 FROM 
  TABLE_NAME
 WHERE 
  Hp= ()Identification
GO                                                                          Results the flowing error: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'."

Comment: ALTER PROCEDURE PRO_NAME (Identification INT)
 AS SELECT
 CASE WHEN CONVERT(MobileAreaCode, int)>1 OR
 CONVERT(Mobile, int)>1 THEN MobileAreaCode+Mobile
 End FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE Hp=(Identification)
GO

Answer (score 4):

You need to store the values you've selected into SQL Server variables so that you can check later on:

```
DECLARE @MobileAreaCode INT
DECLARE @Mobile INT

SELECT 
    @MobileAreaCode = MobileAreaCode, 
    @Mobile = Mobile 
FROM 
    TABLE_NAME
WHERE 
    id = 123456789

IF (@MobileAreaCode IS NULL OR @Mobile IS NULL)
BEGIN
   RETURN NULL
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   RETURN @MobileAreaCode + @Mobile
END
```

I didn't know what **datatype** your columns are (you didn't mention that in your question), so I just assumed they're `INT` - if not, adapt as needed.

Comment: Its not working for me i get return value of some number in the column even if the other column value is null

Comment: Sorry, my bad - some of the values was empty and not null it works - but it returns 0 and not null